# Why the Add-migration command of Code First is including all the database instead of a specific change that I made to an entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, dbcontext

I have a class

```
public class Types
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}

}
```

using code first I created the table of same structure using add-migration and update-database.

but when I added another property to it.

```
public string SystemName {get; set;}
```

and migrated then the script included the whole database in the up() function and that with CREATE even I removed all the previous migration files.

Why ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you removed all old migration files? You should not do it. By migration files entity framework understands which part of database it need to create.

Comment: no that should never effect it, have done this many times and never affected my system.

Comment: Check you ef migrations table in DB then.